# trying to add UILabel to some UIView organized by 2 columns

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel

I'm adding n UILable to n UIView organized by 2 columns but just the first UILabel shows up.

here is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<ieneN; i++){
    UIView *ienaSx = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIView *ienaDx = [[UIView alloc] init];

    ienaSx.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, i*95.0, 160.0, 95.0);
    if(i%2==0)
        ienaSx.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else 
        ienaSx.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UILabel *ienaSxLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    ienaSxLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, (i*95.0)+80.0, 160.0, 15.0);
    ienaSxLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Iena n°: %i", i];
    [ienaSx addSubview:ienaSxLabel];

    [scrollView addSubview:ienaSx];

    ienaDx.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, i*95.0, 160.0, 95.0);

    if(i%2==0)
        ienaDx.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    else 
        ienaDx.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];        

    UILabel *ienaDxLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    ienaDxLabel.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, (i*95.0)+80.0, 160.0, 15.0);
    ienaDxLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Iena n°: %i", i+1];

    [ienaDx addSubview:ienaDxLabel];


    [scrollView addSubview:ienaDx];
}
```

see this picture for a clearer explanation: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/schermata20110716a18064.png/

is there someone that can tell me where i'm wrong?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for setting the label's frame:

```
ienaSxLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 80.0, 160.0, 15.0);
```

The same for

```
ienaDxLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 80.0, 160.0, 15.0);
```

Also don't forget to release your objects (views and labels) after you add them to the superview.

Comment: Yeah, basically the `frame`s are defined w.r.t. the parent view so they shouldn't change.